# probability problem - expectation

Tags: probability

A tourist wants to visit four cities: A, B, C and D. First he chooses one at random. If he chooses A he then randomly chooses among B, C and D. If he chooses B then he randomly chooses among A, C, D. The tourist remembers only the city he's in and not the ones he visited. Find the expectation for the numbers of cities he visits before visiting the four cities.
I haven't really tried much since i don't know where to start...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first $2$ trips, the tourist will have visited $2$ cities.

Let $X$ be the number of extra visits until a third city is visited. Let $Z$ be the number of extra visits beyond that until the fourth city is visited. Then the total number of visits is $2+X+Y$. We want to find the expectation of this, that is, we want to find $2+E(X)+E(Y)$.

Once the tourist has visited the second city, with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ the next visit is to a new city, and with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ it is to an old city. So (expectation of a geometric random variable), we have $E(Y)=\frac{3}{2}$.

Once the tourist has visited the third city, with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ the next visit is to a new city, and with probability $\frac{2}{3}$ it is to an old one. You can now write down $E(Z)$, and conclude what the expected total number of visits will be.